# How to get a form name in php script?

Tags: php, javascript, forms

For my php file, I need to grab the unique form name.

The php file is executed when a user clicks the submit button. However, there are multiple submit button each with the same id, but they all have unique names. I need the name when they click on the submit button.

Comment: post the form, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 way is to put a hidden input inside of your form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="formName" value="[name of form]" />
```

then in your php, you can get it using

```
$form-name = $_POST['formName'];
```

pretty sure there are other ways, but this came to mind first.

Answer (score 3):

you dont want elements in html with the same id - bad practice in general.  Your page will likely load normally but an html validator will notice it as an error.

html validator: http://validator.w3.org/

without seeing your code, its difficult to give you a definitive answer.  if you have miltuple forms you can use hidden inputs.  e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_name" />
```

Otherwise you can use javascript to put data in the form when the button is clicked.  example javascript using jquery

html:

```
<form id="formid" >
    <button type="button" id="someid" onclick="submitForm('btn1')"  />
    <button type="button" id="someid" onclick="submitForm('btn2')"  />
    <input type="hidden" id="btnsubmitid" value=""  />
</form>
```

js:

```
function submitForm(btnID){

    $("#btnsubmitid").val(btnID);
   $("#formid").submit();

}
```